# Upload/create to a folder created from www-data user PHP via FTP user used for VSFTPD, Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, php, ftp, vsftpd

I have two users:
www-data with a group `www-data`
ftp_user used for VSFTPD to connect to the server with group `www-data`

There is a folder owned by ftp_user:www-data for the FTP - `ftp_folder` with permissions:
`drwxrwxrwx 4 ftp_user www-data 4096`

In that folder, I'm using simple `PHP` script to create a dir:

```
mkdir('test', 0777, true);
```

- PHP runs `www-data`.
  The created by PHP folder (`ftp_folder/test`) is owned by `www-data:www-data`, with permissions:
  `drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096`

If I try to upload a file in it (test folder) via FileZilla (ftp_user), I am getting

> 553 Could not create file.

VSFTPD config:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
force_dot_files=YES


file_open_mode=0777
local_umask=033

anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

How to make in that ftp folder all users or both (ftp and www-data) to have full access and when one user create folder/file other user to be with full access for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. Whenever I create folders/files via www-data (PHP). Those files/folders can't be deleted via my system user via vsftp.

I constantly need to run the command on my ubuntu-server: sudo chown -R root:mySystemUser MyWebsiteFolder

after that I can delete the file/folder via vsftp.

HELP, I don't want to need to run this command constantly for new files